# I commented out a method, yet Xcode still remembers it and is giving me an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Here is the error message I am getting:

> -[test1ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a3e300

However, I commented out 'numberOfRowsInSection'... why is xcode still remembering it?

I tried to look through documentation but could not find any thing...

I cleaned the project
I clicked on 'build'

still same problem.

Comment: You commented out the method but did you also remove the call that invokes that method?

Comment: Once that happens (exception breakpoint), use the debugger to check what kind of class that instance (0x8a3e300) actually belongs to (`po`).

Comment: yes i commented everything out... still remembers it.

Answer (score 6):

The `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`  is a `UITableViewDataSource` required method. Which means that your controller needs to implement this.

From [Apple docs for `UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

> – tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  required method
>
> – tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  required method

If your controller is marked as data source for the table view either from the XIB or programmatically like,

```
@interface MyController: UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource> 

@end
```

It will crash at runtime if you comment out the required functions.

To resolve this crash, keep a blank implementation of the method or remove the data source completely.

Hope that helps!

Comment: hi amar, everything is commented out of my project now,therefore there should be no code to even compile except whta comes with a new project when you created it by xcode

Comment: @BridgetCay Sure you have removed the data source connections from the XIB as well?

Answer (score 0):

**Check out UITableViewDelegate**

"numberOfRowsInSection" is required delegate for UITableView in iOS, this is not an optional method which u can ignore.

Answer (score 0):

fixed the problem - I litterally deleted everything out of my project yet it still gave an error - but i missed on thing - the storyboard.

I have one view which contained a table view on there which was still 'hooked' to the .m file which contained that notorious function. I then disconnected it. Now error is gone.